# export to microstation with qgis error

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, dgn, microstation

I want to export my SHPFile into microstation dgn using qgis. But when, I do click right on layer and save as... This message error shows "L'export du fichier vectoriel a échoué.
Erreur : La création du champ Type a échoué (Erreur OGR : CreateField() not supported by this layer"
That tells me that the export has failed !! :/

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but you may want to consider referencing the shapefile into microstation, then copying the elements into the dgn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if QGIS can achieve this natively as I also receive an error (using QGIS 2.14.1-Essen for Win 7 64-bit).

Instead use OGR from the **Processing Toolbox** to convert your shapefile to DGN format:

```
Processing Toolbox > GDAL/OGR > [OGR] Conversion > Convert format
```

Comment: Thank u Joseph :) I didn't know abt this tool.

Comment: Actually I used it to convert my shp layers into one DGN file. But When I used "convert format", I can only select one layer to convert it :/ I still have a problem that I don't know how to select all my layers (point, polyligne and plygone) on the same time to convert them into the same dgn file !!. is this tool can only select one layer to convert it ?

Comment: I'm new with qgis :/ could you help me please with this problem. Thank u :)

Comment: @K.mouna - I see you asked a [separate question ](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195217/convert-shp-to-dgn-with-ogr2ogr) for which I mentioned that I do not think this is possible using ogr2ogr or QGIS. Hopefully I'm wrong but I haven't used dgn files before :)