# Convert SHP to DGN with ogr2ogr

Tags: qgis, ogr2ogr, qgis-processing, dgn, microstation

I want to convert my shp layers into one DGN file using ogr2ogr (QGIS). When I use this tool, I can only select one layer to convert. My problem is I don't know how to select all three layers at the same time and converting them into the same destination dgn file.

[image]

Comment: I want to convert *My ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [OGR Driver Info for Microstation DGN](http://www.gdal.org/drv_dgn.html), you cannot create DGN file consisting of more than one layer:

> DGN files can **only have one layer**. Attempts to create more than one layer in a DGN file will fail.

So I don't think this is possible through ogr2ogr or QGIS. You may need to look for another application.

Comment: Yes that's what I noticed too :/ I can not convert all my layers (point, polyligne and polygone) into the same file with QGIS. But using the "Conversion tool" in ArcGis, I can choose more than one layer and convert them to the same file. :) Thank you a lot for your help @Joseph :) :) :)

Comment: @K.mouna - Awesome, glad you found another way to achieve what you wanted! And most welcome :)